# Results about sentences in second order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose we have a sentence S in first order logic and it's corrospoding sentence S' in second order logic (by simply replacing any predicates in S with variables).

What can be said about S' if?

```
a) If S is satisfiable?
b) S is valid?
c) S is true in a model of size k?
d) S is true in an infinite model?
```

I can't find any information about this online, and was wondering if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Is this hard? E.g. a) $S$ is satisfiable $\iff$ the existential closure of $S'$ is satisfiable. Something similar is true for b). For d), there's a 2nd order sentence that's true only in infinite models, so the conjunction of that with the existential closure of $S'$ is satisfiable.

Comment: This isn't a homework problem. Just reviewing for logic exam. To the second point, this makes sense, however I'm looking for statements like if S is true in a model of size k, then S' is true in every model of size >k or something like that